# Prevent bounce for ScrollablePositionedList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, mobile, scrollable

I jump method (scroll without animation) in ScrollablePositionedList, and if it jumps to the first element, it works file. However, if I jump to the last element in the list, if causes "bounce" effect. For now, I use temporary workaround by setting alignment to about 0.5 or 0.6, but it depends on the device, and doesn't work well sometimes.

Is there a way to prevent bouncing for the last element?

Comment: Not sure if it will work but try setting `physics` property in `ScrollablePositionedList` to `ClampingScrollPhysics` . References [ScrollablePositionedList docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/scrollable_positioned_list/latest/scrollable_positioned_list/ScrollablePositionedList-class.html) and [ClampingScrollPhysics docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClampingScrollPhysics-class.html)

Comment: Tried. Did not work:(

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this?

@Alex did you find anything?

Comment: @flashberry I use jump with alignment argument, with a calculation of proper alignment